# Download manager - for offline content - should I use idleTimerDisabled or background task completion (or none or both)?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I am planning to add a feature where users on Wi-Fi can downloading files sized between 150mb and 1gb so that they can use the app offline.

The download manger will take a time between 2 mins and A few hours to get the content depending on the size of file and the Wi-Fi connection speed.

Many users have an auto lock which will activate after a period of inactivity.  When the device is locked the network connection is killed to preserve battery life (Im fairly sure this is correct as of iOS5?).  This would be frustrating for users as it would frequently suspend their downloads unless they kept the device active.

To get round this I am considering 2 options:

1. Set [idleTimerDisabled](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/idleTimerDisabled) = YES while the app is downloading to prevent the screen locking.  I don't think this is a good use of the properly since the documentation seems to suggest this should only be set for apps.  Also it would unnecessarily keep the screen on, which is not good for battery.
2. Use the background task completion API.  Its its a bit vague how long this will last for, it might not be long enough for the users, but it could be better than nothing.

Are either or both of theses options viable?

Comment: So, what did you end up doing Robert?

Comment: @Sam - Option 2 If I recall.  The background task completion API was very easy to use (just a couple of lines of code), this gave 10 mins of download time.  The proper solution is to use iOS 7's NSURLSession, however it would have taken too much time to refactor for our project.  We did notice some downloaders made use of the `idleTimerDisabled` property tho.  We decided not to use it.